js добавить перенос строки
Из функции возвращаю строку в таком формате
return `>${name} ${value}`;

Нужно чтобы между name и value был перенос строки, дальше я это копирую в буфер
navigator.clipboard.writeText(getStrForCopy());

пробовал "/<br/>" или "" ничего не работает, получается так что в буфере оказывается что-то типа

name "" value


блин даже здесь  сработал, а у меня нет

У меня и стандартный перевод строки сработал и \n
